# Python dict restructure

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

Given the following data structure:

```
out = {
  'foo': { 'public':{}, 'private':{}, 'other':{} },
  'bar': { 'public':{}, 'private':{}, 'other':{} }
}
```

I am attempting to *slice* out parts of the sub-structure to create a new `dict`. My use for this is to respond to requests with all data *except* that marked `private`.

To do the opposite is trivial:

```
response = {x,y['private'] for x,y in out.iteritems()}
```

Which constructs a dict for each `foo` and `bar` containing only the data marked `private`. But is there some functionality in the standard library (itertools perhaps) that would produce the following:

```
out = {
  'foo': { 'public':{}, 'other':{} },
  'bar': { 'public':{}, 'other':{} }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
{x:(y['public'], y['other']) for x,y in out.iteritems()}
```

Although I would prefer to not use a tuple, and not explicitly name each sub-structure, as this is not reusable or scalable.

```
def remove(name, obj):
    return {x:y for x,y in obj.iteritems() if x is not name}
{x:remove('private',y) for x,y in out.iteritems()}
```

This seems to work, but is there a better way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break this down into parts; you want a new dictionary which has some parts removed.  So create a function which can return a dictionary without the elements in question and call this is part of an iterator.

You're using dictionary comprehensions so something like this would work:

```
def remove_items(d, *items):
    """
    Return dictionary copy with some items removed.
    """
    return { a: b for a, b in d.iteritems() if a not in items }

print { x: remove_items(y, 'private') for x, y in out.iteritems() }
```

Comment: This is essentially the last thing I tried, however I like the fact I can specify multiple keys here. This is nice and clean. Thankyou.

Comment: I like that your answer is more general than mine, but I would still write `remove_items` to copy the original and then `del` the unwanted ones. That way you only have to iterate over the [presumably shorter] unwanted list instead of the complete list of dictionary keys.

Comment: @Duncan I was originally going to suggest using del on a copy but went for the one liner instead.  In the case of simple data types such as dicts I suspect this would be quicker.  Where the values to be removed are complex types, copying them just to throw them away again may be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be what you mean?

`respose = {x:{'public': y['public'], 'other': y['other']} for x,y in out.iteritems()}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response = {}
for x,y in out.iteritems():
    response[x] = dict(y)
    del response[x]['private']
```

If you don't mind destroying the original dictionary then just iterate over it `del`'ing the 'private' elements, otherwise you need to copy the second level dicts and then `del` the unwanted items.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to only expose certain data in a response, not destroy the original. Thanks for the answer.